# Mysql SELECT where 2 column match set of values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing **product filter** the point is the more specific the user select the products the less results should appear. At he moment I am writing multiple queries and storing in arrays and checking for array intersect, but the result is opposite, which means when user apply more filters, i will show more products.

So i am thinking there could be a SQL command which I don't know!

simplified example:

```
------------
table "filter"
------------
product
Spec
value


------------
Sample data
------------

book1,page,200
book1,cover,leather
book1,language,en

book2,page,300
book2,cover,paper
book2,language,de

book3,page,150
book3,cover,hard
book3,language,en



SELECT `product` FROM `filter` where  ...
```

how do I select (page=200 and langauge=en)?

Comment: Show the code you've tried.

Comment: so you're using your fancy sql database as a simple key:value store?

Comment: foreach ($a as $k=>$v){
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `spec_product` WHERE `spec_pin` = '$k' AND LOWER(`value`)=LOWER('$v')";
        $res2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql2);

        if ($res2) {
            while ($newArray2 = mysqli_fetch_array($res2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                $product_pin = $newArray2["product_pin"];
                if(!in_array($product_pin,$sp)){
                    array_push($sp,$product_pin);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $r = array_intersect($sp,$p);

Comment: `SELECT field1, field2,...fieldN table_name1, table_name2...
[WHERE condition1 [AND [OR]] condition2.....`

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_where.asp

Comment: the fields are just spec and value but selection is based on the  value of the fields

Comment: Please indicate how the sample data relates to the table.  For example, where is the information about the language stored?

Comment: language is a 'spec' and en is a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If understand correctly you are probably looking for something like this

```
SELECT product
  FROM filter 
 WHERE (spec = 'page' AND value = '200')
    OR (spec = 'language' AND value = 'en')
 GROUP BY product
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 -- 2 here represents number of spec-value pairs
```

Output:

```
| PRODUCT |
-----------
|   book1 |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/edc0ba/3)**

Comment: Nope he wants product name where page=200 **and** langauge=en

Comment: Thank you so much, I think OR needs to be AND because the more filters the less products should show.

Comment: @AK4668 You're welcome. No, `OR` should stay `OR` in that case

Comment: @AK4668 - No. `AND` won't give you any records. That's why we are using `HAVING` clause.

Comment: @peterm, Very elegant solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative, but less elegant. I just wanted to show another way of doing it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT product
FROM filter f
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM filter WHERE spec = 'language' AND value = 'en' AND product = f.product)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM filter WHERE spec = 'page' AND value = 200 AND product = f.product);
```